# Skeptical that new hire is actually working during day - should I address with boss?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

My company is still working remotely due to the pandemic, but has recently hired a new employee. My company communicates internally and with clients via slack, and consequently I am reading or sending messages several times an hour. I have noticed every time I switch to Slack, the new hire's online status indicator always indicates they are away, with the exception being if there is a project meeting they are required to be on, or if I message them I notice their status will eventually change to "online" briefly. For those who don't use Slack, your status is set automatically when the following conditions are met:

> [...] you’re set to active when Slack is open on your desktop or mobile device. You’re set to away after 10 minutes of desktop inactivity, or if you navigate away or close the app on your mobile device.

This is concerning to me, because they were hired with the intent to take over a project I have been working on for several months to allow me to move to new projects. I am considering whether or not to communicate my concerns with my boss, but I am hesitant for a few reasons:

- They could simply be completely closing Slack after they finish sending or receiving messages or finishing meetings. While not impossible, it seems strange
- They have negotiated a different work schedule than typical business hours when they were hired, but this would go against the requirements that were asked of me when I was hired (to be available during normal business hours)

I also don't want to appear as if I am out to get anyone in trouble or cause workplace drama, and it's not necessarily my job to monitor new hires. The new hire in question has been with us for only over 2 weeks. Should I allow the situation more time to see if this is causing issues, should I take these concerns to my boss, or is this something they should themselves be responsible for monitoring?

Comment: "This is concerning to me, because they were hired with the intent to take over a project I have been working on" So, are they taking appropriate steps toward that, appropriate given that it has only been two weeks?

Comment: A smarty-pants move is you message them this:  "Steve, are you there? Your status is on away."

Comment: Determining the actual presence or activity of a person based on their Slack status is a sure fire method for getting it wrong. Keeping tabs on and reporting on an employee who isn't your direct report is a sure fire way to make a mess for yourself and everyone else. Maybe try minding your own business?

Comment: Is there an understanding that all employees be active on slack channels during the work day? I personally hate and view group IM rooms almost as annoying as someone shouting questions into the hallway or cubicle farm, hoping someone will answer them. If you've got a question _for me_ send it to me, but don't expect me to monitor the group chats of 30-40 people and pick out the messages that apply to me.

Answer (score 24):

If the employee is responsive to communication and is fulfilling their obligations according to deadlines then this is a non-issue. Ignore it and move on.

If they are not responsive or if they are not fulfilling their obligations, then that is what you raise with your manager.

Slack status indicators are a red herring.

Comment: And he can put Slack on a mobile device and work on the computer. It's really not that hard to imagine them not constantly IMing people because that's not their actual job.

Answer (score 11):

I have a member of my team who is always set to "offline" on Slack, who is our Principal Engineer.  When I send him a message, he responds within 2 minutes.  It's a red herring, move on.

The real indicator is if this person is not getting their work done.  If the work is not getting done, then you have reason to be suspicious.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that they don't use slack on their computer but rather are just responding via their phone - since they're remote, do they use a vpn / RDP to a virtual machine to do their work, from one of their own computers? If so, and if they don't need to communicate on slack very often, they may not use it on the desktop very often vs just having it on their phone (and thus never being in the app throughout the day unless responding to a ping)

It's possible they are working different hours, it's also possible that they're a contractor rather than a direct employee (and thus.... the business can't set their direct work hours anyways, or at least can't enforce them without potential liability of them actually getting counted as an employee after the fact)

^ This behavior would make more sense to me if it were a contractor or a consultant hired for that specific project, especially if they were juggling other work and were just signing in to your company's specific slack channel to handle the messages / communication they had lined up for that hour / day.

(OP mentions new hire but I'm explaining as if they might have been a contractor hired, as i'm not sure and it is somewhat relevent as it's happening more and more these days as companies are uncertain about budgets to keep employees on)

I would say it depends on your relationship with your manager. If you can find a polite way to mention, hey, i don't know if you're aware of it but I suspect X person isn't logged in throughout the day, they may appreciate it. But avoid doing so in a manner that could come off as looking petty and upset at being replaced. If you're on good general terms / you communicate with your manager often in a manner that is fairly formal, they may not mind. Other managers that are more uptight might see it as you stepping out of your role (which it is, hence only really do this if your manager is fairly comfortable discussing such things with you)

Answer (score 2):

It's not high school.

This is trivially resolved.

Message the person:

> Hey Steve. Your Slack indicates you are "away" all day. Why is that?

It's that simple.

Any normal employee in a business environment, should be able to answer this simple direct question with no issues or stress. (Even if the question comes from a more junior person.) It's completely normal.

It would be very similar to saying something along the lines

> "Hey, I believe your camera is not working."

Which is completely adult and businesslike.

---

***Please note*** as everyone has explained: if you are new to using Slack, if Slack continually shows "away" it ***does not necessarily*** mean the person is "slacking".  They could !! be slacking but there are numerous reasons it might show "away". However, it is a fact that in some teams, you do, in fact, have to have Slack correctly showing that you are literally at the keyboard working (unless away for a coffee etc), indeed that even applies to those who work at the office, not just remote. So it's not surprising or "wrong" to "ask about" Slack etiquette.

Comment: The appropriate answer for that message  would be: "How exactly is this your business?"

Comment: @Hilmar - yes and no.  (Firstly, if someone asked *me* that direct question, (even someone junior to me) I'd simply explain why. It's a business; there's no room for "being offended".  I'd either explain if there's a technical reason, or I'd state that I am out and about a lot, or whatever the answer is.)   Now, it appears OP is *not* a superior of X, but, it appears OP is tasked with ensuring that X takes over some project. The question is completely, totally normal and businesslike. There are many companies where, in fact, you are required to keep slack "alive" all day. Nothing surprising.

Comment: @Hilmar or, it could be "Oh CRAP!  I didn't know, thanks for giving me the heads up.  Which I actually did one time when I accidentally clicked my status to be "away" instead of "Busy" and a coworker let me know

Comment: Indeed, when i didn't understand Slack I had my status on something obscene for weeks and didn't realize

Comment: -1 Among many problems here, OP says, "it's **not** necessarily my job to monitor new hires"

Comment: @DanielR.Collins , its a storm in a teacup, but any normal employee in a business environment, should be able to answer the simple direct question (ie, in this answer) with no issues or stress, as I mention even if it comes from a more junior person.  it's completely normal.  it would be very similar to saying somethin galong the lines "Hey, I believe your camera is not working."  cheers

Comment: @Hilmar I think the conversation could be built up to where you ask that in the end. For example, you're about to switch the project over to this new hire and you could say, "Hey new hire, the project is committed to the repo and if you have any questions please let me know. BTW, your status is away all day, just FYI." And leave it at that. Don't expect an answer.

Comment: @Fattie Personally I wouldn't really care about the status the person is in. Regardless I would send a message during working hours, because that is the agreed upon way to interaction while at home. If after some reasonable timeframe, they fail to answer, and it's not a one-off event but a consistent behavior, I would bring it up with the manager. Statuses do not really mean anything at all because you can still answer and see what is sent to you regardless of the status you're in.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you have any sort of undisputable evidence other than pure speculations based on nothing more than what sort of status they are using. It is a non-issue at this point and I wouldn't bring it up.

Personally I would send messages to this person regardless of the status they are in during normal working hours. If the agreed upon method to communicate with your teammates is via this messenger then that is what I would use. If they fail to answer within a reasonable time frame, and it is a consistent behavior (not a one off event) then I would bring it up with the manager.